# C# GridView alternate the background color vertically and horizontally

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm developing an ASP.NET Web application and I want to alternate the color of the gridview cells like the chess(vertically and horizontally). The colors will be yellow and black.

Comment: Yellow/black is the foreground color or background color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use the RowDataBound event of the GridView, something like this:

```
   <asp:GridView ID="grid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
         DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">

   protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
   {
        if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            return;

        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            TableCell Cell = e.Row.Cells[i];

            // if both row and column are odd, color then black
            // if both row and column are even, color then yellow
            if (((e.Row.RowIndex % 2 == 1) && (i % 2 == 1)) ||
                ((e.Row.RowIndex % 2 == 0) && (i % 2 == 0)))
                Cell.BackColor = Color.Black;
            else
                Cell.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes thank you! it is working. Can I exclude the first column from this? I want the first column to be black because it is a matrix.

Comment: start the for loop at int = 1 this will exclude the first column

Comment: To be the first column black I used the following code(inside row databound) and works perfect.
Thank you. The problem solved.
 
  `string color = "#000000";
            e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("Style","background-color: " + color + ";");`

Answer (score 1):

Set the ItemStyle and AlternatingItemStyle properties, and specify the BackGroundColor and Color properties.  These control those colors.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I forgot to mention that the gridview filled dynamically from a stored procedure that is called on page_load. The GridView is a matrix and the stored procedure includes pivot. So I don’t have columns to convert them to template